# Как получить ответ от яндекс.кассы в нормальном виде?

Tags: php, яндекс-касса

Получаю вот такой результат на создание платежа.

```
YandexCheckout\Request\Payments\CreatePaymentResponse Object ( [_id:YandexCheckout\Model\Payment:private] => 
22c6c4fd3-000f-5000-8000-12cf4dca423a [_status:YandexCheckout\Model\Payment:private] => pending 
[_recipient:YandexCheckout\Model\Payment:private] => YandexCheckout\Model\Recipient Object ( 
[_accountId:YandexCheckout\Model\Recipient:private] => 516545 [_gatewayId:YandexCheckout\Model\Recipient:private] => 
556779 [unknownProperties:YandexCheckout\Common\AbstractObject:private] => Array ( ) ) 
[_amount:YandexCheckout\Model\Payment:private] => YandexCheckout\Model\MonetaryAmount Object ( 
[_value:YandexCheckout\Model\MonetaryAmount:private] => 1000 
[_currency:YandexCheckout\Model\MonetaryAmount:private] => RUB 
[unknownProperties:YandexCheckout\Common\AbstractObject:private] => Array ( ) ) 
[_description:YandexCheckout\Model\Payment:private] => [_paymentMethod:YandexCheckout\Model\Payment:private] => 
[_createdAt:YandexCheckout\Model\Payment:private] => DateTime Object ( [date] => 2018-06-28 09:58:11 [timezone_type] 
=> 2 [timezone] => Z ) [_capturedAt:YandexCheckout\Model\Payment:private] => 
[_confirmation:YandexCheckout\Model\Payment:private] => YandexCheckout\Model\Confirmation\ConfirmationRedirect 
Object ( [_enforce:YandexCheckout\Model\Confirmation\ConfirmationRedirect:private] => 
[_returnUrl:YandexCheckout\Model\Confirmation\ConfirmationRedirect:private] => 
[_confirmationUrl:YandexCheckout\Model\Confirmation\ConfirmationRedirect:private] => https://money.yandex.ru/api-
pages/v2/payment-confirm/epl?orderId=22c6c4fd3-000f-5000-8000-12cf4dca423a 
[_type:YandexCheckout\Model\Confirmation\AbstractConfirmation:private] => redirect 
[unknownProperties:YandexCheckout\Common\AbstractObject:private] => Array ( ) ) 
[_refundedAmount:YandexCheckout\Model\Payment:private] => [_paid:YandexCheckout\Model\Payment:private] => 
[_receiptRegistration:YandexCheckout\Model\Payment:private] => [_metadata:YandexCheckout\Model\Payment:private] => 
[_expiresAt:YandexCheckout\Model\Payment:private] => 
[unknownProperties:YandexCheckout\Common\AbstractObject:private] => Array ( ) )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
json_decode(json_encode($response), true))
```

Answer (score 0):

Используя библиотеку https://github.com/yandex-money/yandex-checkout-sdk-php и функцию unserialize(). Насколько видно по ответу, все классы должны там содержаться.